# Validation when no coordinate is entered

Tags: python

I have a python program and I'm not too sure how to get this to work, it comes up with an error every time I try something. Basically a user is prompted to enter a set of coordinates, and when I press space when I have no coordinates entered it throws an error. I tried using `try:` and `except ValueError:` but no success. I also tried adding an `if (Coordinates == ""):` but also no success.

Here is the code:

```
def GetHumanPlayerMove(PlayerName):
  print(PlayerName, "enter the coodinates of the square where you want to place your piece: ", end="")
  Coordinates = int(input())
return Coordinates
```

Any idea how to solve this?

EDIT: `try and except commands`

```
def GetHumanPlayerMove(PlayerName):
  try:
    Coordinates = int(input(str(PlayerName), "enter the coodinates of the square where you want to place your piece: ", str(end="")))
  except ValueError:
    print(Coordinates)
  return Coordinates
```

Also, what does the `end=""` bit of code at the end of the `print` do?

Comment: Show us the code where you tried `try` and `except`.

Comment: Done. Look at the edited version.

Comment: int(input().strip())?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be running a python3.x script using python 2.x, would you? `raw_input()` changed to `input()`

Comment: @jDo It's source code provided my my exam board. I don't agree with many things they have done in this. And no idea.

Comment: What i mean is: Try running your script with python 3.x or change `input()` to `raw_input()` if you're using python 2.x

Comment: @jDo I'm running python 4.3.1.

Comment: @Filip I didn't know that was out yet :O

Comment: @Filip What input are you feeding the script? Comma separated ints or something?

Comment: @jDo I meant 3.4.1, my bad.
I'm not feeding it anything. It gives me an error before I even have a chance to enter the coordinates.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what's going on. If I'm right, it'll work in Python 2.x (python 2.7 being the most common). I suspect your exam board is using the implicit `eval()` functionality of Python 2.7's `input()` function to make a tuple from input with this format: `3,3` (int, comma, int). It will never be valid if it's cast to int though.

Comment: @Filip Are you allowed to edit the code as you please? You seem to be doing so yet you say it's someone else's code and I got the sense that you  aren't allowed to change it (too much)

Comment: @ jDo Ahh okay I see. It's a source code available to us for the exam. I'm just practicing possible questions, so yes, I am allowed to edit everything as I please.

Comment: At the top of the code it says that it was developed in a python 3.4 programming environment... Which makes what you said before invalid :/

Comment: @Hmm... True. Unless, of course, that's flat-out wrong or the author forgot the difference between python 2.x input() and python 3.x input(). That's probably not likely though. I joined the chat. Maybe we should stick to that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106648/discussion-between-filip-and-jdo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can validate input before change it to `int`.

```
def GetHumanPlayerMove(player_name):
  print(player_name, "enter the coodinates of the square where you want to place your piece: ", end="")
  inp = input()
  if inp and inp.isdigit():
     coordinates = int(inp)
  else:
    return 0
  return coordinates
```

function returns `0` if receives invalid input, else the result itself
`end=""` make the prints keep in the same line and don't send `\n` (new line)

Comment: It threw an error saying: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int`.

Comment: what input do you use?

Comment: It is impossible for input to return a NoneType. If the user just presses enter, it returns and enpty_string, never None

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong:

```
def get_human_player_move(player_name):
    while True:
        coordinates = input("{} enter the coordinates of the square where you want to place your piece: ".format(player_name))
        try:
            return int(coordinates)
        except TypeError:
            print "coordinates must be a number"
```

Why I took the freedom of modifying your code so much?

1. Do never use CamelCase for variables or functions, only for classes
2. No need for a print and then an input / raw_input in PY2
3. Force the user to give you a proper number until he does (while loop)

Comment: Your one throws an error saying: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`.

Comment: What are you entering?

Comment: it seems like something, somewhere in the code, kind of sends the return key signal to input